# ¿como ordeno una lista enlazadas en java?

Tags: java, lista

//no se en donde estoy comientiendo el error deseo ordenar por código del producto en una tabla aplicando el método burbuja

```
public DefaultTableModel ordenar(){

   DefaultTableModel tabla = new DefaultTableModel(); 

    tabla.addColumn("Codigo");
    tabla.addColumn("Nombre-producto");
    tabla.addColumn("valor");


    est_productos reco1 = null;

    est_productos sig = new est_productos();
    Integer [] array = new Integer[3];   
    for(int i=0; i<getcon()-1; i++){

       for(int j=0; j<getcon()-1; j++){
       if(codigo3.getcodigo()<codigo3.getnext().getcodigo()){

       sig.setcodigo(reco1.getnext().getcodigo());
       reco1.setcodigo(reco1.getcodigo());
       reco1.setcodigo(sig.getcodigo());


          }


       tabla.addRow(array);
       }




    }
    return tabla;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nunca inicializas la variable  `reco1`:

```
   est_productos reco1 = null;
   //..
```

Para evitar que te lanze el error deberia de ser:

```
est_productos reco1  = new est_productos();
 //...
```

Comment: Porque el punto negativo? Pueden explicar?